# problemas para ejecutar ng-click angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ayuda, no puedo hacer funcionar ng-click en angularjs dashboard template

Específicamente `<button ng-click="alert()">OK</button>`

*piedad no se mucho sobre web programming*

main.html

```
  <div class="card" ng-controller="trafficDemoCtrl">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <h4 class="card-title mb-0">Pressure</h4>
          <div class="small text-muted">August 2019</div>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-->
        <div class="col-sm-7 d-none d-md-block">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right"><i class="icon-cloud-download"></i></button>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle float-right mr-3" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
               <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Day
               <button ng-click="alert()">OK</button>  
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" checked> Last 12
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Year
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-->
      </div>
      <!--/.row-->
      <div class="chart-wrapper" style="height:300px;margin-top:40px;">
        <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="false" chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick" chart-options="options" chart-colors="colors" height="300"></canvas>
      </div>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('trafficDemoCtrl', trafficDemoCtrl)
trafficDemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];
function trafficDemoCtrl($scope,$window){

  function random(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  }

  var elements = 12;
  var data1 = [];
  var data2 = [];
  var data3 = [];
  var data4 = [];

   for (var i = 0; i <= elements; i++) {
    data1.push(random(50,200));
    data2.push(random(80,100));
    data3.push(147);
    data4.push(686);
  }

  $scope.alert=function () {
    $window.alert('Hello Guys');
  };

$scope.labels = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
  $scope.series = ['Current', 'Previous', 'Low', 'High'];
  $scope.data = [ data1, data2, data3, data4];
  $scope.colors = [{
    backgroundColor: convertHex(brandInfo,10),
    borderColor: brandInfo,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff'

  }, {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: brandSuccess,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff'
  },{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: brandDanger,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderDash: [8, 5]
  },{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: brandDanger,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderDash: [8, 5]
  }];
  $scope.options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value) {
            //return value.charAt(0);
            return value;
          }
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          //stepSize: Math.ceil(250 / 5),
          stepSize: Math.ceil(150),
          //max: 250
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
        hitRadius: 10,
        hoverRadius: 4,
        hoverBorderWidth: 3,
      }
    },
  }
}
```

[código fuente](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template)

código funcionando [aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bksag.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Falta cerrar todos los `<input type="radio" />`

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" /> Day
<button ng-click="alert()">OK</button>
```

Comment: la sintaxis correcta se supone que es ```<input type="radio">```

Comment: Debes cerrarlo @asterix, si no queda el button dentro y por eso no funciona el click!

Comment: de todas formas eso no soluciona el problema. Estoy editando esto https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template

Comment: @asterix que raro que no funcione, puedes agregar el código para hacer una prueba?

Comment: sí lo hice agregué lo que comentaste. Pero si funciona ahora. Mira https://i.imgur.com/I5Yfafo.jpg

Comment: excelente, si te sirvio mi respuesta recuerda marcarla para ayudar a otros. Saludos!

Comment: la marqué pero tengo pocos puntos, no me deja.

Answer (score 2):

No debe estar cargado bien el Javascript.

Tienes doble punto (error de sintaxis) al definir el controlador:

```
angular.module('app')..controller('trafficDemoCtrl', trafficDemoCtrl)
```

Comment: Cierto, pero fue un error de copy paste. El código está bien en esa parte. Al final funcionó, pero solo era una prueba para probar el ng-click, porque lo que la verdad me interese que funcione es agregandolo dentro de <input ng-click="function()">.  Gracias  https://i.imgur.com/I5Yfafo.jpg